# Python : Generate avro schema using pandavro invalid datatype64[ns]

Tags: python, mysql, avro

I want to generate an avro file from mysql table. I'm currently using pandavro. But pandavro not yet supports datetime datatype. How can I solve the problem? Not using pandavro is fine.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Convert the datetimes to strings via strftime.
(2) The strings should then write to the avro.
(3) Convert datestrings back to datetime when reading the avro.

Something else to consider is using a parquet file, which supports datetime.